# Error adding xrandr mode

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I am following the following [xrandr documentation on adding a missing resolution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions), and am getting an error that I can't resolve.

```
user@box:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then it says to use --newmode to create the mode

```
user@box:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

and finally add the mode to the output. This is where I get the error, and I can not figure out what exactly is going on. Nothing I found online could resolve this issue.

```
user@box:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

PLEASE HELP!! I am so sad and desperate! :P

EDIT: Here is some additional very important revelations.

There is some docs on my exact error....

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#xrandr_BadMatch

And I have confirmed in xorg logs that I have a bad EDID....

> [    27.493] (WW) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0 does not have an EDID, or its EDID does not contain a
>   [    27.493] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     maximum image size; cannot compute DPI from DFP-0's EDID.

Comment: The line `xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 "1920x1080_60.00"` should be `xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1920x1080_60.00`

Comment: No it doesn't. Either way, it results in the same error.

Comment: Please can I have the link to the steps you followed ?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add it.

Comment: I have seen your link and your have `"1920x1080_60.00"` when you should have `1920x1080_60.00` like I had pointed out. The error is in the `parameters` your passing to `xrandr`

Comment: I agree the error is in the parameters passed, but adding or removing quotes to either or both of the parameters has no effect - the same error message results with all possible combinations of quoting either/all/or those two params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is, you might not have anything connected to the port you are trying to send the `xrandr` command to.  I tested some on my system here and received the same error.  Make sure that you are running the command on the correct port.  I will use an older monitor of mine as a demonstration.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cvt 1280 1024
# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1280x1024_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

Here's the error.  The next line shows me all my connected DVI ports.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr | grep -w connected
DVI-I-1 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
```

As we can see, mine that I want is connected to `DVI-I-1`, so I corrected the line to match my connected monitor.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1280x1024_60.00

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr | grep -w connected
DVI-I-1 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
```

And now, my monitor took the new mode and looks good.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: If i run xrandr -q it only lists DVI-D-0 and HDMI-0. My card only has 1 DVI-D out, so I am certain DVI-D-0 is correct. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @ScottF What does `xrandr | grep -w connected` return?

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what is shown in "connected" as well as the name I used for "newmode" line, and I still get the same error.

Comment: @JosephK What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: The problem turned out to be that the NVIDIA driver no longer supports xrandr beyond query-mode.  You have to specifically allow settings not found in monitor-detection, add that flag plus settings, etc.

Comment: Maybe Xorg config like `Option "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes"` might help?